# phone number verification using parse server , swift and Twilio

Tags: swift, parse-platform, twilio

Im trying to use phone number verification in my app. During sign up the user will be asked for their phone number and be sent a verification code and they will enter the code and if it matches they can proceed. I have the cloud code ready but I'm not sure how exactly to call this from the app. Any help would be appreciated

What I want to be able to do is when they enter their phone number and press continue, first check that the phone number is a valid phone number, then send the sms code. finally segue to a verification view where they enter the code, if it doesn't match display an alert, if it does, log the user in

Cloud code:

```
// Require and initialize the Twilio module with your credentials
var twilio = require("twilio")("twilioAccountSid","twilioAuthToken");

Parse.Cloud.define("sendVerificationCode", function(request, response) {
    var verificationCode = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    user.set("phoneVerificationCode", verificationCode);
    user.save();

    twilio.sendSms({
        from: '+14123854839',
        To: request.params.phoneNumber,
        Body: "Your verification code is " + verificationCode + "."
    }, function(err, responseData) {
        if (err) {
          response.error(err);
        } else {
          response.success("Success");
        }
    });
});


Parse.Cloud.define("verifyPhoneNumber", function(request, response) {
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    var verificationCode = user.get("phoneVerificationCode");
    if (verificationCode == request.params.phoneVerificationCode) {
        user.set("phoneNumber", request.params.phoneNumber);
        user.save();
        response.success("Success");
    } else {
        response.error("Invalid verification code.");
    }
});
```

swift code send code :

```
  @IBAction func send(_ sender: Any) {

        PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "sendVerificationCode", withParameters:  ["phoneNumber" : phoneNumber], block: { (results, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let aVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerificationCode") as! VerificationCode
                self.present(aVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("sent")
            } else {
                print ("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Your cloud code isn't going to work verifying numbers.  Cloud code doesn't have an authenticated user, so Parse.User.currentUser() doesn't return anything. You can use `request.user`, but that's a shell object with just their id and session I believe, so you need to fetch it before you can get any data from the object. You also either have public write permissions on user objects, which is a huge security flaw, or are missing passing either the user's session or master key into the save call.  You should disable public write access to your users.

Comment: Twilio does have a method in their API for verifying a number is a mobile number.  You'd want to update your sendVerificationCode method to use that before sending the SMS and return an appropriate error.  Everything you're asking is beyond the scope of a single SO question, though. You've broken it down into parts. Perform each step. Get yoru buttons working without the server code, transitioning between screens. Then add the server code in and use the results. Ask individual questions if you have them.  Also, Twilio has a verification API that you may find useful and more reliable.

Comment: Hey there - Twilio/Authy Developer Evangelist here. Like Jake said we have an API for doing phone verification, here’s how I use that in a sample Swift app: https://github.com/robinske/phone-verification-swift